# jQuery scroll up and down on a div

Tags: jquery, css

I've created a DIV element with the stylesheet below

```
#myDiv nav {
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 315px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 60px 0 0 0;
}
```

Now there is a list of UL>LI elements in it that can be of any height, I created two buttons UP and DOWN to navigate this "#myDiv nav" and the jQuery is below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var scrollh  = 0
    var scrollv  = 0

    jQuery(".up_nav").on("click" ,function(){
        scrollv = scrollv + jQuery('#myDiv nav').innerHeight()
        jQuery('#myDiv nav').stop(true, false).animate({
            scrollTop: (jQuery('#myDiv nav').offset().top - scrollv)
        },500);
    });

    jQuery(".down_nav").on("click" ,function(){
        scrollh = scrollh + jQuery('#myDiv nav').innerHeight()
        jQuery('#myDiv nav').stop(true, false).animate({
            scrollTop: scrollh
        },500);
    });
});
```

**PROBLEM**

The first few clicks on UP and DOWN works well with me but after these few clicks, The scrolling goes extreme UP or extreme DOWN.

I wanted this to be a normal behaviour, Scrolling up and down according to the height of UL element that resides in "#myDiv nav" and in small steps.

**EDIT**

I've uploaded the working version of my problem to the jsfiddle website
[Link to JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1bbjLjf4/), You will notice the problem after clicking the up or down button few times.

I understand my jQuery logic has a flaw in it but i am unable to understand it.

Comment: It'd be grand if you could include a JSFiddle so people can see the problem in action!

Comment: I added the jsfiddle link on your request

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue with your fiddle.

Comment: My logic is wrong, Try clicking the DOWN button three times and then clicking the UP button, It will be then going extreme up or extreme down on clicking either of these buttons but the logic should be that it goes a step down and a step up on clicking either of these buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a little closer to what you're looking for. It's implemented with the concept of pages.

http://jsfiddle.net/ue94jj60/6/

```
var Grid = function () {
    var self = this;

    var page = 1,
        nav = null;

    this.init = function () {
        nav = $('#myDiv nav');

        $(".up_nav").on("click", function () {
            self.scroll(page - 1);
        });

        $(".down_nav").on("click", function () {
            self.scroll(page + 1);
        });
    };

    this.pages = function () {
        return Math.round(nav[0].scrollHeight / nav.innerHeight());
    };

    this.scroll = function (p) {
        if (p < 1 || p > this.pages()) {
            return;
        }

        page = p;

        nav.stop(true, false).animate({
            scrollTop: (page - 1) * nav.innerHeight()
        }, 500);
    };

    $(this.init);
};

var grid = new Grid();
```

You can also scroll it programmatically:

```
grid.scroll(3);
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution and the correct approach, I wish i could thumb up your answer but again you did a tremendous job on helping me here

Answer (score 0):

You can make

```
ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}
```

and next just change top style on ul after clicking on the button.

Check example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DariuszMusielak/oxgbyk6b/1/ **<---- UPDATED**

**UPDATE v2** 
http://jsfiddle.net/DariuszMusielak/jrtfrgo2/

Comment: The problem with your working is that it goes infinite number down as you keep clicking the down button.

Please have a look at my jsfiddle link to see how i am doing it and what is getting wrong

Comment: It isn't problem. You can alway set margin for scrolling to down.

Comment: I updated for you my example on your code. Check it out

Comment: I checked the updated example but this is not going to help.

The best way would be to use offset like i have used in my example and correct the logic because it doesn't really move the nav itself and secondly your variable **marginBot** can't have a fixed value since the UL tag can be of any height.

Comment: Hmm what do you think about using normal css scroll?

Comment: This is how i would like to have it working as i showed in my example, I avoid the ugly scroll bars and don't really like using external libraries to modify the look either.

I might also need to understand the fallback of this jquery if the browser doesn't support javascript but that would be another topic and a new question.

Comment: You fixed my logic and is working good now but @Timmerz approach is far much better than mine or yours, Big thanks for getting the logic correct but i will be using a tweaked version of Timmerz solution.